# Convert midi data into lead sheet with roman numeral theory

Tags: notation, composition, ableton-live

I am working on making an original composition for a uni assignment and I am wondering how to notate this progression into essentially sheet music, I have converted it into a score with musescore, but I have to write a lead sheet as well, I am wondering how I would write this? the chord progression is this, but inverted chords (Im pretty sure :s) Am (C), Asus2 (B) Third chord im unsure G? and A (E) hopefully this makes sense to someone out there. TIA

[image: Screenshot of chord progression in ableton live 10]

Answer (score 2):

Already made a fully notated score of it with Musescore? Good job. Now analyze the Musescore version's chords individually.

To make the lead sheet, leave the melody on top. Remove the chords and put the analyzed chord results on top of the first notes they apply for (e.g. put A/E on top of the notes for the 4th chord).

Yes, you read that right. Notate inversions with a slash: put the root chord on the left and put the bottommost note on the right of that slash. For example, notate your first chord as Am/C.

Hope this helps. If this isn't clear enough, just comment on the bottom.